# me marca errores de librería mi proyecto en IntelliJ

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, librería, aplicación-escritorio

he estado trabajando en un proyecto en IntelliJ con JavaFX y postgres y todo bien pero hoy que vuelvo a abrir mi proyecto se inundo de errores por todos lados por las librerías (aun que si las tiene). [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probe correrlo y todo bien, no me marcaba ningún error. la aplicación ya la tenia lista y al querer hacer pruebas dos de ellas me arrojaron un error "JavaFX Application Thread" el cual es raro por que esas funciones ya estaban al 100. supongo que debe de tener relación con lo de los errores de librería y como sea ya intente quitándole y volviéndole a poner las librerías y siguen los errores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probaste limpiar la cache de intelliJ?

Comment: no, no me traerá problemas ?

Comment: Para esto, hay que ir a la pestaña Problems del Project settings y ver qué pasa. Limpiar la caché sólo borra la caché de intellij, que tiene clases que ya están guardadas y cosas así.

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó exactamente lo mismo, y al día de hoy 09/02/2024 lo pude solucionar borrando la caché como recomendó @Alfabravo
Para borrar la caché la ruta es la siguiente:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches... -> Invalidate and Restart
```

Espero que a otro le sirva también ;)